# HTML special characters in MySQL query, not working

Tags: php, database, mysqli, special-characters

I'm creating a dynamic website in which a user specifies a bunch of options in a form, and then hit's submit, at that point I have a php script that uses the `$_POST` variable to access the values the the user had selected. I do a query on the database and pull all the matches, and display a listing of the items on a new page. The user can then navigate through the available options, and should they click one, it takes them to the dynamically created page for that item. I am passing the name of the item through the URL, and then use it to find the specific item with that name in the database. The problem is that items with titles or name that include characters like an apostrophe(or single quote), a + symbol, or the & symbol don't get passed through the url properly, and it results in the information not being extracted from the database. For instance, if I have an item named "Tap & Barrel", if I assign that exact string like so:

`<a href="pub_temp.php?name=Tap & Barrel></a>`

then when the new page for Tap & Barrel loads, none of it's information has been extracted and the URL of the pub_temp.php is something like:

```
/pub_temp.php/name=Tap & Barrel
```

and for some of them, like the ones with single quotes, it's as if everything is ignored after, and it only passes everything in the string that comes before that character.

I ahve tried to use htmlspecialcharacters, in conjuction with ENT_SUBSTITUTE and ENT_IGNORE, but have not been successful, does anyone know a work around for this?

Comment: try mysql_real_escape_string() it will neglect  single quotes

Comment: @NirajKarmick I just tried that, and no luck.